# Binance Chain and Binance Smart Chain token price matching

Tags: binance, binance-smart-chain, binance-chain

In this site https://www.binance.org/en/assets-proof it says that-

> The same token can circulate on both networks, and flow between them bi-directionally via a cross-chain communication mechanism.
> • The total circulation of the same token should be managed across the two networks, i.e. the total effective supply of a token should be the sum of the token’s total effective supply on both BSC and BC.

So how is a specific token kept interconnected on Binance Chain as well as Binance Smart Chain and how is the price kept same for a specific token on both the blockchains.
Also how is the supply maintained for the tokens.